# Is the Roslyn model so C#/VB.NET centric that it precludes XAML analysis now and in the future?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, roslyn

I have just read [the blog entry by JetBrains (Resharper) that suggests that Roslyn could never do XAML analysis](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/04/10/resharper-and-roslyn-qa/):

> Another core difference is that Roslyn covers exactly two languages, C# and VB.NET, whereas ReSharper architecture is multilingual

(quote from resharper blog)

For the uninitiated Resharper can do very good static analysis on XAML code allowing code completion and refactoring together with C#.

I am curious. Is the Roslyn architecture general enough to be extended to other languages than C# and VB.Net such as XAML or is it very specific.

To avoid suggesting this is opinion based I am looking for **evidence in the source**. Obviously any code can be refactored /re-engineered over time to fit some other purpose but I'm only interested in current **evidence** in the source or references to quotes from Roslyn develepors indicating that there is **intent** to extend Roslyn as an analysis engine to other languages such as XAML.

Comment: I see exactly one occurrence of `XAML` in that entire page, and it's in a comment saying "Roslyn is faster in rename refactoring by now because it can’t rename member references from XAML," - how do you go from that to "Roslyn could never do XAML analysis"?

Comment: I've added a quote in an edit

Comment: I believe C#/VB.NET are procedural/object-oriented languages whereas XAML is declarative. There's elements of declarative programming in C#/VB.NET but I wouldn't call them that. (Wikipedia calls them multi-paradigm languages). XAML is pretty much exclusively declarative. Independent of what Roslyn does or doesn't do, I imagine it would be very hard to write a compiler that spans the entire procedural/declarative divide.

Comment: This blog entry contains a lot of ... "challengeable" .. quotes. Roslyn is a compiler service. The Roslyn repository "happens" to contain two parser implementations that hook into that service, for C# and VB.NET. To support another language, one has to create another implementation (eg using ANTLR) that will hook into that service.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think that's true. Roslyn is a service that you can't use to access the internals of a compiler. It's not a service for writing new compilers. At least it was never presented that way.

Comment: @svick Didn't say it is, quite the opposite. Its a service where compilers will plug in to expose their models.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to teach "languages" in a paragraph or two. People tend top call many things "language" and in some very general sense they might be but in real-world of programming "language" means programming language. In that world, XAML is not language at all :-) because you can't write code in it.

XAML is a data description format and yes in a very general sense it can be called a language (has some basic constructs, their combination rules, and the result denotes something meaningful). But it doesn't have even its own syntax - it's XML. So it belongs to a group with say MSBuild and HTML. The kind of analysis you could, in theory, do with that is entirely different and very much related to the actual domain that the format describes.

For MSBuild files, you could write some code to analyze dependencies it denotes and says try to find and point out holes in that but all you need for that are a few standard .NET classes. You don't need a parser, don't have any code generation, etc. You just load XML like any other and you already have everything and cam cruise around and dig out relations. Same for XAML. For everything XML-based "Roslyn" is XmlDocument, or XPathDocument.

Roslyn breaks it basks to produce a tree structure that allows you the same kind of cruising freedom that you get just by loading the XAML document into XmlDocument.

Answer (score -2):

I made a simple analysis of a freshly-cloned copy of the Roslyn source code (specifically, the `Compilers` directory), to see how much code is shared between then languages and how much is language-specific.

The results:

- in total there are 3072 code files (.cs and .vb file extensions), totaling 78 MB
- out of that, the `CSharp` directory contains 1060 code files, worth 30 MB
- the `VisualBasic` directory contains 1165 code files, which amount to 41 MB
- that leaves 847 files and 7 MB for common code

So, as you can see, the the two compilers share only a relatively small part of their code. If you want to create a compiler for a new language, basing it on Roslyn won't help you much.

Comment: With Roslyn, the platform is not the same as the language. Less common code probably means that it's easier to create a new language and integrate it on the platform. I'd be more interested in the contents of the `Core` folder and whether these classes allow or prevent the integration of a language like Ruby or F#

Comment: -1: Your results do not support your conclusion in any meaningful way.

Comment: The conclusion sounds reasonable to me, insofar as the preexisting "common code" is only going to make up a small part of the whole work necessary to add another language to Roslyn; but it doesn't exactly answer the question, which was whether Roslyn *can* conceptually accomodate languages other than & different from VB.NET and C#.